# Der Pharao – die Pharaonin?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Weder im Duden noch im [dazugehörigen Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharao) findet sich eine weibliche Form der Bezeichnung *Pharao*, obwohl weibliche Pharaonen nicht unbekannt sind. Die Artikel zweier solcher Königinnen, [Kleopatra](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleopatra_VII.) und [Hatschepsut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatschepsut), verwenden in der Einleitung *weiblicher Pharao* oder *altägyptische Königin*, weiter unten aber das (naheliegende) Wort *Pharaonin*. Auch Google liefert ein paar Treffer für *die Pharaonin*. Hier noch der erste Absatz des oben verlinkten Artikels zu *Pharao*:

> Der Begriff Pharao geht auf das ägyptische Wort *Per aa* („großes Haus“) zurück, das ursprünglich weder ein Herrschertitel noch ein Eigenname, sondern die Bezeichnung für den königlichen Hof oder Palast war. Die Verwendung von „Pharao“ bezüglich der Person des Königs kam erst im Neuen Reich ab Thutmosis III. auf, dennoch war danach diese Titulierung des Königs von Ober- und Unterägypten nicht die Regel und kaum Teil des offiziellen Protokolls. Im Koptischen – der letzten Sprachstufe des Ägyptischen – ist es dann das normale Wort für König.

Ist nun "Pharaonin" eine korrekte Bezeichnung für eine altägyptische Königin?

Comment: Ich glaube Pharaonin ist "eingedeutscht". Man müsste schauen was auf den Wänden steht.

Comment: So eine Freundin gefragt die Kulturgeschichte Nord-Ost Afrikas studiert hat: Nein. Keine weibliche Form offiziell belegt. Also eingedeutscht.

Comment: Ich werfe mal Pharaonesse in den Ring, dazu gibt es aber auch keine nennenswerte AnzahlTreffer bei  Google.

Answer (score 1):

Es kommt auf den Kontext an, in dem du diesen Titel verwenden willst. Jeder, der Deutsch beherrscht, wird verstehen, was mit »Pharaonin« gemeint ist. Daher kann man dieses Wort auch (fast) überall dort verwenden, wo von einem weiblichen Pharao die Rede ist. Insbesondere in gesprochenem Deutsch und in einem gewöhnlichen Gebrauchstext sollte das kein Problem sein.

Nach meinen Recherchen gibt es aber den offiziellen Titel »Pharaonin« nicht. Auf eine Tafel, die in einem Museum unter einem Bild der Herrscherin Hatschepsut abgebracht ist, wird man nicht »Pharaonin Hatschepsut« schreiben können. Das wäre falsch. Dort muss »Pharao Hatschepsut« stehen. Man kann auf demselben Täfelchen ja dazuschreiben, dass sie einer der wenigen weiblichen Pharaonen war, um auf diese Weise ihr Geschlecht zu thematisieren.

Comment: Man kann also "die Pharao" sagen?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Nein. Das Wort »Pharao« ist grammatikalisch eindeutig männlich. In einem Kontext, wo du für dieses Wort einen Artikel verwenden würdest ist es imho erlaubt »die Pharaonin« zu verwenden. Beispiel 1: »Die Gemahlin von  Thutmosis II war Pharao Hatschepsut, die auch den Beinamen „Die erste der vornehmen Frauen“ trug.« Beispiel 2: »Die Gemahlin von  Thutmosis II war die Pharaonin Hatschepsut, ...« In Beispiel 1 ist »Pharao« der offizielle Titel der Herrscherin, in Beispiel 2 wird das Wort nicht als Titel, sondern als eine Art Berufsbezeichnung verwendet.